# Вопросы про Collector.Characteristics

Tags: java, java-stream

1. Как `IDENTITY_FINISH` может ускороить работу коллектора? Я так понял, это сэкономит пару вызовов стэка (в случае с `finisher` который возвращает тот же `supplier`), a учитывая как долго может работать коллектор в зависимости от размера стрима, так это вообще ничего.
2. Для чего `CONCURRENT` может использоваться, ведь `combiner` в любом случае вызывается при использовании `parallelStream()`, не зависимо от того, создан ли коллектор с параметром `CONCURRENT` или нет.
3. Как `CONCURRENT` влияет на обычный stream()?
4. Для чего нужен `UNORDERED`, если при использовании `parallelStream()` все в любом случае будет не сортировано, а при использовании stream() все будет обрабатываться в том же порядке в котором передали. Или я не правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. совершенно верно, `IDENTITY_FINISH` никак не ускорит работу коллектора, он просто показывает, что коллектор не нуждается в финальной трансформации (finisher).
2. `CONCURRENT` (согласно описанию) это характеристика accumulator, а не combiner, а именно говорит о том, что accumulator можно вызывать из разных потоков(Thread).
3. `Collector.Characteristics` - это характеристики коллектора, а не стрима (Stream;  приходится использовать такой англицизм во избежании путаницы, т.к. "поток" скорее ассоциируется с Thread). Т.о. обычный стрим тоже может быть собран параллельно, см. `Collectors.groupingByConcurrent()` `Collectors.toConcurrentMap()`
4. `UNORDERED` - говорит о том что коллектор не соблюдает порядок элементов, например собирает их в Set. Наличие этой характеристики является одним из требований позволяющих параллельную сборку.
   см [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

> A concurrent reduction should only be applied if the collector has the Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED characteristics or if the originating data is unordered